# How can I use a CyanogenMod theme with a stock rooted Galaxy S III?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, themes

I'd like to make this my phone theme https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ramazor.theme.freedea&feature=more_from_developer

But it seems to require me changing my phone over to Cyanomod or something of the like. I'm not sure if I'm ready for that, but I do already have root access via SuperSU and was wondering if there might be another way to go about using this theme.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S3 SGH-T999.

Comment: The method you used to root and how you control root access isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. The Cyanogen theming engine is specific to CM and derivative ROMs.

Samsung stock ROMs have Touchwiz UI, which is a proprietary layer. Theming CM to look like Touchwiz, or creating mashups would be easier because of CM's open nature. Some carriers might give packs, like Sprint ([source](http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-galaxy-s-ii-epic-4g-touch/171209-touchwiz-themes.html)).

You can install a different launcher and install themes on it, of course. Go Launcher, for one, has  many themes.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you cannot, themeing features are specific to CyanogenMod, and if attempting to apply this on top of a Stock ROM, will either result in Force Closes, or boot-loops.

You cannot have it both ways. Go down the CyanogenMod route and then the themeing will work, ***OR*** forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

It is originally part of the T-Mobile theme engine, which is open source so you can implement in other roms, but you will need a rom that has it built in

http://code.google.com/p/android-theme/wiki/TMobileThemeEngine